# Android Studio (2.1.1) presents "no target device" although 'adb devices' command finds the device

Tags: android

This scenario started after Android Studio upgrade to version 2.1.1

- Windows recognizes the phone and it's file system
- USB debugging option is enabled (is shown in List of devices attached) 
  -'adb devices' command finds the phone (!)

And still, Android studio shows "no target device" and fails to run the app.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution:

This step solved the problem: 
Go to Run, "Edit Configurations...", and in the Deployment Target Options section, choose "Show Device Chooser Dialog" instead of: Target = "USB Device".

Comment: I was using a more random fix - running the Android Device Monitor and then messing with Tools, Android, Enable ADB Integration also worked around this problem.  Your solution is much more elegant.